# Change MASM console window size

Tags: windows-7, console, masm, masm32

I'm making a program that requires a console window size of at least `80 X 80` to print a matrix of squares of size `21 x 18`. These squares need a space between them to be distinguishable so specifically, a `43 x 37` window. At the present I use an `80 x 25` window setting, which is not enough.

I use the code below to change the screen size:

```
MOV AH, 0
MOV AL, 3 ; use 80 x 25 screen
INT 10H
```

according to this [site](http://assemblytutorial.blogspot.com/2010/09/interrupt-10h-service-0-set-screen-mode.html). I tried to change `MOV AL`, n with other options but whenever I use the sizes above 3, the console pauses and displays a dialog box that contains the message:

```
16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem

Command Propmt - sample.asm
This system does not support fullscreen mode...
```

I am using Win 7 Ultimate 32-bit, and `masm32`.

**Is there any way to change my console window size larger than `80 x 25` in MASM without the error?**

Comment: A console is a window these days but it was not back in the stone age when programmers wrote 16-bit code like that.  The BIOS simply doesn't have the support for setting the window size.  Get ahead by using the 32 in masm32.

Comment: Have you tried using the actual window size/buffer properties from the command prompt? Not sure if the dimensions will stay the same when compiling the asm program though.